# ¿Cómo devolver una tabla temporal desde un procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente código

```
-- Start of our procedure
delimiter //

CREATE procedure getData(in monthBegin int, in monthEnd int)
wholeblock:BEGIN
  DECLARE sumaTotal INT;
  DECLARE x INT;
  SET sumaTotal = 0;
  SET x = monthBegin;
  
  loop_label: LOOP
    IF x > monthEnd THEN
      LEAVE loop_label;
    END IF;
    SET sumaTotal = sumaTotal + (SELECT IFNULL(sum(total), 0) FROM VENTAS WHERE MONTH(dateVenta) = x);
    SET x = x + 1;
    ITERATE loop_label;
  END LOOP;
    SELECT sumaTotal;
END//
-- End of Procedure
delimiter //
```

Este código me devuelve la suma total de ventas que hubo entre ese rango de meses mediante un ciclo, funciona correctamente pero ahora lo que necesito es que me devuelva una tabla con cada resultado de cada mes, por ejemplo, supongamos que de enero a marzo :

| Mes | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Enero | 4300 |
| Febrero | 2200 |
| Marzo | 4380 |

Adjunto la estructura de mi tabla ventas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: te recomiendo sustituir los loop por while que son mas fáciles de realizar y si puedes añadir la tabla que tienes los meses si puedes de ventas :-)

Comment: Agrupar la consulta por meses no te dio resultado? con `GROUP BY`

Comment: @JavierG.Raya gracias por la recomendación lo tomaré en cuenta, estoy practicando el tema de loops más que nada, ahora incorporo la tabla de ventas

Comment: @Liyo disculpa la ignorancia amigo como puedo hacer eso? estoy practicando más que nada

Comment: Así como tienes un SELECT fuera del ciclo, saca la consulta donde asignas `sumaTotal`, sin paréntesis, pero mantenla dentro del ciclo: `END IF; SELECT MONTH(dateVenta), IFNULL(sum(total), 0) FROM VENTAS WHERE MONTH(dateVenta) = x; ITERATE ...`. Aunque realmente no necesitas el procedimiento, concuerdo con que un `GROUP BY year(dateVenta), month(dateVenta)` es suficiente.

Comment: @Sal Cómo quedaría la consulta con el `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Si puedes agregalo como respuesta para yo marcarlo como solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas el procedimiento, con una agrupación basta:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
SELECT date_format(dateVenta,'%M'), sum(total)
  FROM VENTAS
  WHERE dateVenta between '2022-01-01' and last_day('2022-03-01')
  GROUP BY year(dateVenta)
         , month(dateVenta);
```

La primer línea es para que salgan los nombres de los meses en español, puede que no sea necesaria o puedes configurar el idioma a nivel sesión.
Tendrás que cambiar las fechas del `between` según los meses de consulta que necesites.

Comment: Excelente, es justo lo que buscaba. Gracias por la ayuda funcionó muy bien.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, enhorabuena :-)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```sql
DECLARE @tablaTemp TABLE (mes VARCHAR(255), total INT) 
DECLARE @contador INT = 1 
DECLARE @mesActual VARCHAR(255)

WHILE @contador <= 12 BEGIN 

    SELECT @mesActual = MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(@contador, '%m'))
    FROM VENTAS
    WHERE MONTH(dateActual) = @contador

    INSERT INTO @tablaTemp(mes)
    VALUES(@mesActual)

    INSERT INTO @tablaTemp(total)
    SELECT SUM(total)
    FROM VENTAS
    WHERE MONTH(dateActual) = @contador
    
    SET @contador = @contador+1

END

SELECT * FROM @tablaTemp
```

Me comentas si te sirvió, lo estoy haciendo sin probar ya que no tengo una BD similar a la tuya para hacer el testing.

Comment: Lo estoy tratando de ejecutar pero no me deja... No me marca ninguna salida tampoco, no se si haya error de syntaxis o a lo mejor la forma de como lo estoy guardando, lo puse en mi procedimiento almacenado entre los delimiters, el END // si lo dejo me marca error pero si solo pongo END lo quita, pero no lo ejecuta

Comment: Si hay error en la sintaxis te lo marcaría en la línea donde está mal. Puedes pasarme alguna imagen de tu error?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V0KPfdGjb97kLRLzGJ06nvgJSGBNlQ1K/view?usp=sharing Aqui esta la imagen

Comment: Qué te marca el tooltip?

Comment: DECLARE is not valid at this position for this server version

Comment: Al quitar el END // el error se quita, pero ese END // es necesario para que el procedimiento almacenado se ejecute, al borrarlo y tratar de ejecutar no me muestra ninguna salida o algo, entonces no se que pueda ser, te muestro imagen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JXgpk7IekKTwIhoLZYHkI3p5GA0V7JjC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Creo que lo está creando, fíjate si ya está creado y ejecutalo ahí.

Comment: Si pensé eso pero no, no lo crea. Tu puedes ejecutarlo? con alguna tabla simulada solo con que tenga la columna de dateActual

Comment: Ahh yaa vi, no estás colocandole un nombre eso se pone con `AS nombreSP`, luego de cerrado el último paréntesis de los parámetros.

Comment: Me marca así ahora
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14aH98NRRgyWm-T7mLBsITQ1pr1pKWAaZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: MySQL no soporta el tipo de dato `TABLE`.

Comment: @Sal entonces lo que trato de hacer no se podrá?

Comment: Sí se puede, pero no con esta respuesta.

Comment: @Sal que me sugieres intentar amigo?

Comment: Solo debes colocar el TEMPORARY antes de TABLE. También se trata de investigar un poco, no todo te lo van a dar masticado.